# how to set a bufferSize for the main grid in extjs 5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I need to set bufferSize to a main grid.Could anyone please say me how to set a bufferSize. I have no idea of where to set the bufferSize

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant code here first along with what you have tried so far

Comment: Sorry, and Thank You so much for your concern. I found the way to use the bufferSize.